# Is it OK to write one JavaScript file containing multiple modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It just comes to my mind that most AngularJS (*.js) file I have seen so far only contains one module, and the name of the module is not always the same to the file name.

I would like to know, whether it works by putting multiple modules inside one AngularJS (*.js) file.

Also, how does the server find the correct module name when web page makes a function call? By searching every file in the directory in a brute-forced way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put as many modules as you want in a file (not necessarily best practice though). Angular knows which module to load because you register each module with Angular.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
```

That way it doesn't have to look for modules based on convention.

Answer (score 2):

A module name is referenced in your HTML by using `ng-app="yourModule"` on an HTML element. Having several modules in a single file is not an issue at all. It's actually what minification and obfuscation processes do for production ready code: Combine all you Javascript code in a single file.

What I would suggest is:

- Use several files in development mode for the sake of clarity
- Use minification to have just one file in production for efficiency purposes

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is okay to put multiple modules in a single file.  You have to register all available modules before the app is bootstrapped otherwise it will give you a dependency error.  The page on [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) explains it all.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use different file for each module declaration. You can take a look at the following guide: [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules)

You register your each module using angular.module, and you define your services, controllers etc using your defined modules.

```
angular.module("myApp", []); // module is registered
angular.module("myApp").service("myService", function(){}); // service is declared for myApp module.
```